# Similarity between trees according to the number of common subtrees in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am studying Prolog for an universitary exame using SWI Prolog and I have some problems to understand what my teacher do in this example (it seems to me that is is incomplete) that implement the predicate:

```
k(T1,T2,N)
```

that is **TRUE** if **T1 and T2 are trees and if they have if they have exactly N subtrees in common** (a subtree is common between two trees T1 and T2 if this subtree exist both in T1 and in T2)

He give me another predicate **T(t)** where t is a specific tree and T(t) give me all the subtrees of t (if you want to see a graphical interpretation of this thing you can see the slide 18 of this file: http://www.informatica.uniroma2.it/upload/2012/LPDA/08_Lezione_ZNZ.pptx )

So he say that:

```
k(T1,T2,N)
```

is **TRUE** if is TRUE that: [image: condition]

In practice **it is TRUE that the trees T1 and T2 have N common subtrees if it is TRUE that the intersection of the subtrees of T1 (give from the T(T1) predicate) and all subtress of T2 (give from the T(T2) predicate) is precisely N in module (ie as a number)**

Ok, so go on: he **define the trees** in the following way:

```
tree(F, LIST_OF_SUBTREES).
```

where R is the root of the current tree

So go to implement the predicate **k(T1,T2,N)** that is TRUE if the trees T1 and T2 have N common subtrees, using the previous property.

This predicate have to use an **EXAUSTIVE SEARCH of the subtrees in the trees T1 and T2**

Then he implement the **k/3** predicate in this way:

```
k(T1,T2,N) :- t(T1, ST1),
              t(T2, ST2),
              intersect(ST1,ST2,LST),
              lenght(LST,N).
```

This seems to me pretty clear (correct me if I'm wrong):

- **t(T1,ST1)** put in ST1 the list of all the subtrees contained in T1
- **t(T2,ST2)** put in ST2 the list of all the subtrees contained in T2
- **intersect(ST1,ST2,LST)** put in LST the list of the commons subtrees of ST1 and ST2
- **lenght(LST,N)** put in N the lenght of the commons subtrees of ST1 and ST2

So the predicate **k(T1,T2,N)** it is true if the calculated value of N unifies with the given N value.

Untill here I think that all is clear...bu now I have some problems to understand how he implement the **t(T,STL) predicate that take a tree T and put in STL the list of all its subtrees.

He give me the following code:

```
t(T,STL) :- bagof(ST, st(T,ST), STL).

st_r(tree(A,_), tree(A,[]).

st_r(tree(A,R), tree(A,R1) :- st_l(R,R1).

st_l([],[]).
st_l([X|R],[X1|R1]) :- st(X,X1),
                       st_l(R,R1).

st(T,T1) :- st_r(T,T1).

st(tree(A,R),T1) :- member(T,R),
                    st(T,T1).
```

Regarding the predicate:

```
t(T,STL) :- bagof(ST, st(T,ST), STL).
```

I think that simply execute the **bagof** built in predicate where **ST** is the **subtree** object that, if satisfy the goal **st(T,ST)** is put into the **STL** list (the list of subtree)

But now I am not understanding how the **st/2** predicate (my goal) work !!! Someone can try to explain me the logic of this predicate and of the related **st_l/2** and **st_r/2** predicates?

And please, I have also some doubts about how to concretely build two trees that I can use to test this program. Can you give me two simple trees to use for the testing?

At last I think that, in this example, missing the **intersect/3** predicate

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the naming it's a bit cryptic, and I'll try to guess it.

- `st/2` should stand for subtree, its purpose is to enumerate, on backtracking, all subtrees.
- `st_r/2` should stand for subtree_root. It separately return the *root* and the *leafs*.
- `st_l/2` then should stand for subtree_leafs. It makes a list of 'flattened' trees, replacing actual subtrees.

I would disagree that st/2 enumerates *only* subtrees. Actually, it returns *more* trees, because of the pruning performed by the first clause st_r. This seems an unusual definition to me - but nevertheless, *it's* a definition.

The predicate intersect/3 is defined in SWI-prolog library(lists) as intersection/3.

After two typo correction, that code gives to me

```
?- t(tree(x,[tree(u,[]),tree(v,[tree(p,[]),tree(q,[])])]),L).
L = [tree(x, []), tree(x, [tree(u, []), tree(v, [])]), tree(x, [tree(u, []), tree(v, [tree(p, []), tree(..., ...)])]), tree(x, [tree(u, []), tree(v, [tree(..., ...)|...])]), tree(x, [tree(u, []), tree(v, [...|...])]), tree(x, [tree(u, []), tree(..., ...)]), tree(x, [tree(..., ...)|...]), tree(x, [...|...]), tree(..., ...)|...].
```

Comment: Tnx for your helo but this example still remain difficult to me.
It seems to me that don't work well: for example if I say to enumarate all the subtrees of the tree: t(tree(X, [tree(u,[]), tree(v,[])]), SubTrees).

This is a simple tree having only a root and two leaves it found the following subtrees: X (that's ok), the entire oringinal tree (that's ok), the u node (strange behavior?), the v node (strange behavior?) but don't find the legal subtree like: the root X and the leaf u, the root X and the leaf v
It seems to me that don't work very well !!! Do you think so? Tnx